# How to configure sound system to use stereo on bluetooth headphone and use internal microphone?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I am using PX7 Bowers & Wilkins bluetooth headset, it has an internal microphone. I understand that it is impossible to send high fidelity playback when I use the microphone of the headset, but ubuntu simply doesn't use the internal mic, and does not send stereo whatever I do. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: So you already know (apparently) that it's either HFP (mono + mic) or A2DP (stereo, no mic). What is the question?

Comment: @ChanganAuto The issue is that the second option does not work. The audio is always mono, and I am unable to change othe Mic to the onboard version and use change the audio strea to A2DP. The question is how to resolve it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put addition info there and not in the comments.